# Partially rebuilding tesseract dictionary

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am doing OCR of food items on a restaurant menu. I know what each of the items in the menu are and would like to create a traineddata file that only contains a dictionary of words I know are in the menu.

All of the documentation on building dictionaries I've seen involve starting from scratch. Is there a way to use the existing traineddata, but not have to rebuild the dictionary from scratch?

Thanks.

NOTE: I do not want to use the user-words file because it appears that this simply **adds** to the selected dictionary, rather than **replaces**.